# Can I use a client side access/refresh token to access Google APIs on server

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-calendar-api

I want to use a oauth access/refresh token, that I got when user authorized my Google app on an iPhone, to access Google APIs on a PHP server. I was able to do this quite easily on Facebook Graph API.

Is it possible in Google APIs? If yes, here is my confusion:

- I created a Google app for iOS in Google Cloud console for connecting to Google Calendar API on iPhone. Do I have to create another Google app in cloud console, with platform type "Web", for accessing the Calendar API from a web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be very careful about terminology. In the API console you firstly create a **project**. Within that project you may create any number of client **applications**. Each client application has a unique client id.

So if your question is, do you need to create another client application for web, the answer is "you should, but you (probably) don't need to". I share a single ID between 3 client applications and it works. At some point I will probably go back and separate them into 3 separate client applications.

Comment: To add, although there is no documentation to confirm it, I suspect that if your app is creating files in Drive, they will be opened by the same application that created them. Bear that in mind if your project has multiple apps.